# Thermodynamic-Fuel and efficiency

Tags: physical-chemistry, everyday-chemistry, thermodynamics, fuel

Why is the maximum theoretical efficiency of Ar engine higher than that of Nitrogen engine? On a molecular level.

For an Otto Cycle

- $\mathrm{Eff} \le\left(1-r^{1-\gamma}\right)$
- $\gamma=\dfrac{C_p}{C_v}$
- $r=\dfrac{v_1}{v_2}$

Sys. Fluid

- Nitrogen, $\gamma=1.4,\ r=10,\ \mathrm{eff(max)}=60.2%$
- Argon, $\gamma=1.67,\ r=10,\ \mathrm{eff(max)}=78.5%$

Comment: I want to point to [this page](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation) in our [help] and [this meta post](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here/88#88), which describe the tools we have available for formatting maths.